# What does "snooze like a lump" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

What does "snooze like a lump" mean?

I heard it in a movie description to describe a scene of a man sleeping soundly. I can't find anything on the Internet that indicates "like a lump" is idiomatic. Or did I hear it wrong. I am putting the [audio clip here](https://clyp.it/xinibyvq) (uploaded to an audio sharing site Clyp) for reference.

Comment: You heard it correctly. I haven't heard this particular phrase, but it certainly reminds me of "sleep like a log," which simply means to sleep very soundly. There is also the phrase "sitting like a lump (or bump) on a log," which describes someone who is lazy or useless, just sitting around when they probably should be doing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is very lazy or inactive -- either in general or just at the moment -- people used to say that he was "lazy as a lump on a log". That is, he was just lying there doing nothing like a piece of wood.

I suspect this phrase is a variation on that.